# Почему не работает ширина для элемента в JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот основной фрагмент кода. Проблема в том, что с помощью `span.style.display = "block"; span.style.width = "280px";` я ограничиваю ширину для ввода текста, но проблема в том, что это ограничение не работает, а почему — непонятно.

```js
btn.onclick = function addTask() {
  if (input.value) {

    let elem = document.createElement("li"),
      subtaskBtn = document.createElement("button"),
      span = document.createElement("span");
    subtaskBtn.textContent = "Добавить подзадачу";
    span.textContent = input.value;


    subtaskBtn.className = "subtask-btn";
    span.style.display = "block";
    span.style.width = "280px";

    elem.append(span);
    list.append(elem);
    elem.append(subtaskBtn);
    elem.className = "elem";

    input.value = "";

  } else alert("Необходимо ввести задачу!");

};
```

```html
<input id="input">
<button id="btn">btn</button>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Нужно смотреть, какие ещё стили влияют на ваш span после его вставки. 

Возможно наличие перебивающих стилей на тот же span. В браузере в  панели разработчика смотрите результирующий css span.

Или у родителя могут быть заданы стили, которые меняют поведение width (например, display: flex). 

Попробуйте также использовать свойство max-width.

Comment: Во вставленном сниппете всё работает... или результат должен быть не таким? P.s. Такое "ограничение" можно сделать через CSS, `#list span { display: block; width: 280px; }`. А если display: block, то можно вместо span сразу создавать div)

Comment: рабочий пример, укажите background этому спан и будет видно как он стал 280px